# Remove rows containing identical or word-permuted sentences from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, stringdist

I have a data frame with text

```
TERM
good morning
hello
morning good
you're welcome
hello
hi
```

I would like to filter out all duplicates and all with the same words but in different order. So that I get:

```
TERM
good morning
hello
you're welcome
hi
```

I know how to get the distance of two words with stringdist.

```
stringdist(stringOriginal,stringCompare,method=qgram)
```

But since I have very long data frames I don't want to loop through all entries.

How can I filter out the similar terms?

Thx
Joerg

Comment: You could devise a brute force method with `strsplit` and the set functions `union` and `intersect` or `setdiff`.

Comment: It would be useful to modify the question to include a small example of the kind of data frame you are starting with, along with the desired output.

Comment: Using `stringdist` you could do: `library(stringdist); sdm <- stringdistmatrix(DF$TERM, DF$TERM, method = "qgram", useNames = "strings"); sdm[!duplicated(sdm),]`

Answer (score 2):

Break it up into words, sort the words in each record and keep rows for which the sorted words are not duplicates.  No packages are used.

```
subset(DF, !duplicated(lapply(strsplit(TERM, " "), sort)))
```

giving:

```
            TERM
1   good morning
2          hello
4 you're welcome
6             hi
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "TERM
good morning
hello
morning good
you're welcome
hello
hi"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```